# Testing asyn function using jasmine

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am working on writing the test case for a async function which has callback functions.
This is the function; I am working on.

```
AuthenticationService.login($scope.username, $scope.password, 
            function(error){
                $scope.showLoginError(error);
            },
            function(){
                $state.go('staff');
            }
        );
```

---

```
this.login = function(username, password, errCallBack, successCallBack){ ... }
```

---

I am writing a test for Login. I am stuck on it for days. Will appreciate help and time!!

Comments if you required more info.

Comment: More info required.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249634/testing-an-angular-authenticatedservice-using-jasmine
please check this link. I, actually, post the complete code here. hope this could make my ques more clear. (clear like mud!! lol)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jasmine docs:Asynchronous Support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

Example:

```
it("async execution test", function(done) {
    //write your async spec
    login(username, password, function(){
             fail('Error callback called!!');
         }, successCallBack){ 
             done();
         })
  });
```